# Fetching a DataFrame into a Case Class instead results instead in reading a Tuple1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a `case class` :

```
case class ScoringSummary(MatchMethod: String="", 
TP: Double=0, 
FP: Double=0, 
Precision: Double=0, 
Recall: Double=0, 
F1: Double=0)
```

We are writing summary records out as:

```
summaryDf.write.parquet(path)
```

Later we (attempt to) read the parquet file into a new dataframe:

```
implicit val generalRowEncoder: Encoder[ScoringSummary] = 
    org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[ScoringSummary]
val summaryDf = spark.read.parquet(path).as[ScoringSummary]
```

But this fails - for some reason `spark` believes the contents of the data were `Tuple1` instead of `ScoringSummary`:

```
Try to map struct<MatchMethod:string,TP:double,FP:double,Precision:double,
Recall:double,F1:double> to Tuple1, 
but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$
.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$
ResolveDeserializer$$fail(Analyzer.scala:2168)
```

What step / setting is missing/incorrect for the correct translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Use `import spark.implicits._` instead of registering an Encoder**

I had forgotten that it is required to import `spark.implicits`. The incorrect approach was to add the `Encoder`: i.e. do ***not*** include the following line

```
implicit val generalRowEncoder: Encoder[ScoringSummary] = 
org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[ScoringSummary]   // Do NOT add this Encoder
```

Here is the error when removing the `Encoder` line

> Error:(59, 113) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. 
>   Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes)
>   are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing
>   other types will be added in future releases.
>       val summaryDf = ParquetLoader.loadParquet(sparkEnv,res.state.dfs(ScoringSummaryTag).copy(df=None)).df.get.as[ScoringSummary]

Instead the following code should be added

```
import spark.implicits._
```

And then the same code works:

```
val summaryDf = spark.read.parquet(path).as[ScoringSummary]
```

[image]

As an aside: *encoders* are not required for `case class`'es or `primitive` types: and the above *is* a `case class`.  `kryo` becomes handy for complex object types.

Comment: and what if you want kryo?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Added explanation about why/when `kryo` were necessary into the answer.